# Writing and Invoking Methods

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am in a beginner Java class and now learning about methods. I am completely lost on how to program the following:

Write a class named Test and include a method called findAverage where it takes the integer sum and integer count as input parameters and returns the double average.

Write the main method in Test class that invokes the findAverage method after an unknown number of scores are read in (the sentinel is -9). The output will be the number of scores, the sum of those scores and the formatted average to 2 decimal places.

An output could look like:

Enter a score <-9> to exit: 73
Enter a score <-9> to exit: 87
Enter a score <-9> to exit: 90
Enter a score <-9> to exit: 80
Enter a score <-9> to exit: -9

Number of scores: 4
Sum: 330
Average: 82.50

Can someone please help me understand how to code this in the simplest way? Thanks.

Comment: I'd say ask your teacher for clarification.  I'm *certain* that they covered this before; you may just need a refresher.

Comment: I suggest you google for writing basic java programs with `main()` you'll find lot of references. Work with those examples and if you're stuck somewhere, post your code to get help with that :)

Answer (score 0):

You should create the Class Test and the method findAverage within it.

```
Public Class Test {

    // Whether you call this class from another or this is your main class, you should put or not some attributes. 

    public findAverage (int sum, int count){

     // Code to calculate the average.
    }
```

I don't know if I'm answering your question correctly, but this is basically what you're asked to do. Create your code to do the console asking for numbers and then call findAverage.